# Sorting a returned JSON array by date

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Sorry if this is a really n00b question, but I am just getting into rails and can't figure this one out.

I am currently working with Analytics from a site. And want to put the data into a chart. However when I get the data back the stuff I want isn't in order. At the moment the data returned is:

```
{"legend_size":1,"data":{"series":["2013-06-20","2013-06-21","2013-06-22","2013-06-23","2013-06-24","2013-06-25","2013-06-26"],"values":{"undefined":{"2013-06-26":41,"2013-06-24":2,"2013-06-25":55,"2013-06-22":0,"2013-06-23":1,"2013-06-20":0,"2013-06-21":0}}}}
```

And what I need is the ["data"]["values"]["undefined"] bit to be ordered by date.

I know it's a simple question. But I have looked everywhere and can't figure it out.

Comment: You can't really sort an object, are you trying to only sort the keys?

Comment: I need to sort it together really, so I can plot it into a graph with the date(key) being the label and the value being the point on the graph

Comment: Javascript objects (hash) is not guaranteed order, so I doubt the library cares if values are sorted or not. Have you tried just sorting the series array? I have a hunch that array is used to order the values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I said in the comment you can't really sort and object as it has an arbitrary order, so you must use an array.

My solution would be:

```
    var objectFromAnalytics = {"2013-06-26":41,"2013-06-24":2,"2013-06-25":55,"2013-06-22":0,"2013-06-23":1,"2013-06-20":0,"2013-06-21":0},
        toSort = [], 
        dateParts;
    for (var date in objectFromAnalytics) {
       dateParts = date.split("-");

       toSort.push({ date: new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[2]), value: objectFromAnalytics[date] });
    }


    var sorted = toSort.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.date < b.date ? -1 : a.date > b.date ? 1 : 0; //you can change this to sort by value if you want
    });

//sorted == [{ date: dateObject, value: value from analytics} , { ... }]
```

You can probably get away doing this in a few less lines, but I think is understandable this way :)

Comment: Creating a bunch of Date objects is a little heavyweight. You could just sort the strings lexicographically. The < and > operators work fine on strings.

Comment: Yup, good point, so you don't have to do the `new Date` and the `split`